# Unix - Sed Command Related

Tags: sed, csv

#filename as $1

#business name as $2

#updated in the year $3
#It can match to any commas inside quote values as long as it is before the matching V for postal code. They all start with V.

./script6_1.sh bcindigenousbusinesslistings.csv "B.*" 2021

To find all business that starts with B updated in 2020 or later..

#The first sed is to put from line 2 to the last line
#The second sed : At the beginning of the line, it can match up to any pattern until the V (Postal code) then it will stop
$3 will match any number that has pattern from 20(1 to 3) and (0-9) for the last digit

```
*sed -n '2,$p' $1 | sed -e 's/^\('$2'[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,.*[^V],\)\('$3'202[0-9]\)/\1\2/'*
```

The main point is to extract 3 column, each separate by commas.
Business,Description, Address.
The last column is Year updated.
Inside the column description, there may be more commas separated.

I am having error in this as it just print out all the line, without extracting the matching pattern.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please review your post to use the formatting tools available. It is currently difficult to read. Also, please include example input and desired output, and describe exactly what you tried (in particular if this is a homework assignment) and where it failed along with possible error messages or an example of the wrong output.

Comment: Your code seems to use the arguments in `$1`, `$2` and `$3` unquoted. There is no example of the data in the question. If you're working with CSV files, maybe use a CSV parser (such as `csvkit`) instead of `sed`?  As AdminBee said in a comment: Please take some time to reformat your quesiton so that it is readable.

Comment: Crosspost: https://askubuntu.com/q/1346619/631600

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with columns inside a line rather than the entire line, then `awk` or `perl` would be a much better tool for this job than `sed`.

And, since you need to cope with quoted fields (with commas inside them), you'd be better off using `perl` because it has a [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/release/Text-CSV) module that parses CSV files like that.  You could do it with `awk`, but you'd have to write your own parser to deal with quotes and commas inside fields.

If you're running Debian or similar, install with `apt install libtext-csv-perl`.  Other distros probably have it packaged too.  Otherwise, install it with `cpan`.

The following is a fairly simple example of what you can do with `Text::CSV`.  Run `man Text::CSV` for details.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

use Text::CSV qw(csv);

my ($filename, $search, $year) = @ARGV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({allow_whitespace => 1,
                          allow_loose_quotes => 1,
                          quote_space => 0,
                         });

open(my $in, "<", $filename) or die "couldn't open $filename: $!";

my @headers = $csv->header($in);
pop @headers;                   # discard last field from @headers
$csv->say(*STDOUT, \@headers);  # print the headers

while (my $row = $csv->getline($in)) {

  # note: perl arrays start from zero, not one. So $row->[0] is
  # the first field.  $row->[3] is the fourth.

  if ($row->[0] =~ m/$search/i && $row->[3] == $year) {
    pop @{ $row };  # discard last field (year)
    $csv->say(*STDOUT, $row);
  }

}
close($in);
```

Save this as, e.g., `extract.pl` and make it executable with `chmod +x extract.pl` - same as you would for a shell script.

You haven't given sample input or output in your question, so I've had to make up some nonsense.

Given the following input file, `input.csv`:

```
business,description,address,year
"ABC","sells some items","123 Somewhere Street, Somewhere, V1234",2020
"BCD Co.","sells some items","123 Somewhere Street, Somewhere, V1234",2021
"BBB Pty Ltd","sells some items","123 Somewhere Street, Somewhere, V1234",2020
"BXYZ","sells some items","123 Somewhere Street, Somewhere, V1234",2021
"CDE","sells some items","123 Somewhere Street, Somewhere, V1234",2020
"DEF","sells some items","123 Somewhere Street, Somewhere, V1234",2020
```

It will produce the following output:

```
$ ./extract.pl input.csv '^b' 2021
business,description,address
BCD Co.,sells some items,"123 Somewhere Street, Somewhere, V1234"
BXYZ,sells some items,"123 Somewhere Street, Somewhere, V1234"
```

i.e. all business names beginning with "B" or "b" (the regex match is case-insensitive) with year 2021.   Only the first 3 fields are printed.

Note how the output has quoted fields only where it is essential (i.e. where there are commas inside the fields).  If you want fields containing spaces to be quoted too, change `quote_space => 0` to `quote_space => 1` in the script (or just delete that line since quoting fields with spaces is the default for `Text::CSV`)